# Cannot Remove the word 'ARRAY' when displaying search results

Tags: php, arrays

How would I remove the word 'ARRAY' from my search results. Here is the function that is performing the search. Also, I am pulling the data from a mysql db. Everything works great except the word 'ARRAY' printing on top of the results.

```
<?php

$sql_statement = "SELECT title, type, pubdate, isbn ";
$sql_statement .= "FROM booklib ";

if($keyword != 'ALL') {
    $sql_statement .= "WHERE title LIKE '%$keyword%' ";
}

$sql_statement .= "ORDER BY title, type, pubdate, isbn ";

$result = mysql_query($sql_statement);

$outputDisplay = "";
$myrowcount = 0;

if(!$result) {

    selectResults($statement, $db);
} else {
    if($keyword == 'ALL') {
        $outputDisplay = "<h1>Current Titles: </h1>";
    } else {
        $outputDisplay = "<h1>Current Titles that match: '$keyword'</h1>";
    }

    $outputDisplay .= list($title, $type, $pubdate, $isbn) = explode('*', $line);

    $numresults = mysql_num_rows($result);

    for($i = 0; $i < $numresults; $i++) {

        $myrowcount++;

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


        $title = $row['title'];
        $category = $row['type'];
        $pub_date = $row['pubdate'];
        $isbn = $row['isbn'];

        $outputDisplay .= "<br>$myrowcount.$title";
        $outputDisplay .= "<br>Category: $category";
        $outputDisplay .= "<br>Publication Date: $pub_date";
        $outputDisplay .= "<br>ISBN: $isbn</br>";
    }

    print $outputDisplay;
    getServer();
}
```

Comment: I bet that you somewhere have `echo $arr` (where `$arr` is an array) in your code. Search for it.

Comment: It's most probably a debug print left in `selectResults` function.

Comment: Where is `$outputDisplay` being originally defined? All mentions to that variable in this function are concatenations.

Comment: That's not working code.  `$numresults` isn't defined, neither is `$result` and you never echo or return `$outputDisplay`.

Comment: `ARRAY` is somewhere else in the code.  Not here in what you provided.

Comment: It isn't a debug print left in selectResults function unfortunately. All other questions are addressed with edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is this line that does it:

```
$outputDisplay .= list($title, $type, $pubdate, $isbn) = explode('*', $line);
```

Assignment operations return the value that is being assigned. `explode` returns an array that is assigned to the variables in `list`. Basically, apart from the side effect of assigning variables in `list`, it's as if your code was doing this:

```
$outputDisplay .= explode('*', $line);
```

If you try using an array as a string, PHP casts the array to a string that has the value  `"array"`. In addition, a notice is generated but it is probably not shown because your `error_reporting` setting doesn't allow output of `E_NOTICE` errors.

Comment: What would be the correct syntax for the desired output?

Comment: @user3010201 My guess is skipping that line altogether. `$line` is not set anywhere in the script that is posted.

Comment: That was it. Appreciate the assistance. Sucks being a newbie!